# Get Direct Child - Not Nested Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a layout such as this:

```
<ul id="tax_id">
    <li>
        <label>Input One
            <input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox One
        </label>
        ... elements ...
        <ul class="children">
            <li>
                <label>Input Two
                    <input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox Two
                </label>
                ... elements ...
                <ul class="children">
                    ... elements ...
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whenever I check an input, I' like the next children UL to display or not display if unchecked. The problem I keep running into is that if I use `find()` it will also select the nested children, which is not what I want.

Some stipulations is that I can't have additional classes or IDs as this is on a WordPress platform, category metabox but I want to use Jquery to manipulate the data. My jquery is something like this:

```
$('#tax_id li label > input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent('label').parent('li').find('ul.children').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent('label').parent('li').find('ul.children').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsvwxtfc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.children()` instead of `.find()`:

```
$('#tax_id li label > input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent('label').parent('li').children('ul.children').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent('label').parent('li').children('ul.children').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

As per the doc:

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()`
>   only travels a single level down the DOM tree...

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: That's the function I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: what if another ul.children in that li?

Comment: @BhojendraSah Valid point. I don't think that's the case, but if it were, I would guess the OP wants it to behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) and [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq) like below:

```
$('#tax_id li label > input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent('label').nextAll('ul.children').eq(0).css('display', 'block');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent('label').nextAll('ul.children').eq(0).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried `.next()` and it doesn't seem to work. It may be picking up on the next element as `ul.children` is not directly after the `label`. Check out / try out the fiddle linked in my question.

Comment: Oh, you've another elements too? then use `.nextAll('ul.children').eq(0)`